# Image names with international characters - 404 error

Tags: ssh, images, ftp, batch-rename

Hi I'm trying to figure out what's wrong, and maybe someone can help me out.

I recently moved a bunch of images over to a new server and imported them into my wordpress database. Many of these images had international characters in their names - like "æ" "ø" "å"

Now when trying to access them through the browser, I get a 404 error.

Viewing them with FTP everything looks fine, and even when copying the file url from FTP and pasting into browser the international characters are intact - but still 404.

Example of file name: `laks-med-nykål.jpg`

However then when copying the url from the address bar and into notepad I get this:

`laks-med-nyk%C3%A5l.jpg`

Messing with this for quite some time I discovered that replacing "%C3%A5" with "a%CC%8A" seems to do the trick, and the image shows as it should.

However I don't quite understand what's wrong and why this is.

`%C3%A5 = å`

`%CC%8A = ̊`

So `a%CC%8A = å`?

This is getting me confused, and something has to be wrong somewhere with the naming of the files.

Hope someone can help me understand this, and what needs to be done to correct all the files that has this error in them.

Thanks!